# Pushing Data into empty Array - React useState() Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to declare an empty State for wrong answers in my Quiz-App like this:

```
const [wrongAnswers, setWrongAnswers] = useState();
```

But if I try to fill it up with data (I want to make it an Array of Objects) it always return undefined. I try it like this:

```
    const getWrongAnswers = () => {
    const result = birds.filter((bird) => bird.status === "wrong");

    setWrongAnswers([...wrongAnswers, result]);
  };
```

If i declare my state as an empty Array it'll always give me an empty Array, same with an emptry Array of Objects.

I don't know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

You initialise it with empty array while declaring.

```
const [wrongAnswers, setWrongAnswers] = useState([]);
```

and filter returns array so use spread operator instead of just result

```
setWrongAnswers([...wrongAnswers, ...result]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
If I do so my state variable "wrongAnswers" stays an empty Array, do you have another idea?